# Calling one stored proc from another - issue with syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored proc which performs some joins etc. To return a certain value for a field in the returnset, I have another stored proc, which I call. However, one of the parameters needs to be a calculated value returned for another field in the original resultset (if that makes sense), e.g.

```
SELECT @S = (CONVERT (NVARCHAR (50), DateDiff(minute, CONVERT (CHAR (24), [PI9_StartDT],
108), CONVERT (CHAR (24), [PI9_EndDT], 108)) / 60)) + ' ' + 'Hrs' + ' ' +
SUBSTRING(CONVERT (NVARCHAR (50), (DateDiff(minute, CONVERT (CHAR (24), [PI9_StartDT],
108), CONVERT (CHAR (24), [PI9_EndDT], 108)))), CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT (NVARCHAR (50),
(DateDiff(minute, CONVERT (CHAR (24), [PI9_StartDT], 108), CONVERT (CHAR (24), 
[PI9_EndDT], 108)) / 60)), 2), 3) + ' ' + 'mins'

exec @OUT = [MUJV].[FailPassPI9] GarrisonName, @S, SCPCategory, @S
```

I need to pass that calculated value as a stored proc parameter, as above.

This does not work, however. What I am trying to do is include @S (that sum is used to return a field in the result set) as a parameter to my stored proc. As you can see, it is quite complex.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: You say "This does not work, however." but what error are you getting?

Comment: Why not pass `PI9_StartDT` & `PI9_EndDT` to the `FailPassPI9` procedure and let it form the string?

Comment: I dont see any FROM in the first "set" - it's not clear what it's doing.

Comment: not sure what is the error so can't help much. but try set @OUT = exec mujv.failPassPI9 and parameter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are getting the wrong result in your variable. Here are 2 examples you can consider for better performance and readability:

```
DECLARE @PI9_StartDT datetime = getdate()
DECLARE @s varchar(max)
SELECT @S = cast(datepart(hh, @PI9_StartDT) as varchar(2)) + ' Hrs ' +
            cast(datepart(mi, @PI9_StartDT) as varchar(2)) + ' mins'

SELECT @s = stuff(convert(varchar(5), getdate(), 108), 3, 1, ' hrs ') + ' mins'
```

I will not try to guess why and how your script is failing, I can't based on the current information.